# JIRA - how to get reports programmatically?

Tags: python, jira

I use JIRA as a bug tracker and I built a Python tool that converts JIRA tasks report (got as XML from the 'Views' menu) into MS Access records that are user by another tool.

Ok, that's done, Python's the greatest !

Now I'd like to know how I can automate the 1st part, i.e. creating the report programmatically, ideally:

- in XML
- with the same format as the one provided by the 'Views' menu
- using python of course !

Well, of course I can use other languages and other formats, I was just describing the perfect world ! I don't know if JQL could be used in any way, or if JIRA plugins are useful (I saw notably a Python CLI but I don't know if its features are powerful enough)...

Thanks for your advice/experience/ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose JIRA through:

- SOAP (currently the preferred way)
- XML-RPC
- REST API (still under development)

All of which can be easily consumed in Python client.

See: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+RPC+Services

Comment: I don't think that REST api is currently available for production Jira

Comment: This advice is highly outdated.  Atlassian retired that page two versions ago.